# How to get array of checked Values from the nested JSON Object

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a nested json having the check key with boolean values. I want name key value only for those with check is true in a result array.

Sample JSON

```
 const treeMetaData = [
{
  name  :  'database',
  checked : true,
  schemas  : [
    {
      name  : "schema1",
      checked : true,
      tables : [
        {
          name  : "table1",
          checked : true,
          columns : [
            {
              name  : "column1",
              checked : false,
            }, 
            {
              name  : "column2",
              checked : true,
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      name  : "schema2",
      checked : true,
      tables : [
        {
          name  : "table2",
          checked : true,
          columns : [
            {
              name  : "column4",
              checked : true,
            }, 
            {
              name  : "column5",
              checked : false,
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },

  ]
}]
```

The the output I need

```
 ["database", "schema1", "table1", "column2", "schema2", "table2", "column4"]
```

Really need help and want the optimized approach becaue this treedata is large in size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use recursion, and get the property that has an array value, so to know where to recurse into:

```js
const listNames = arr =>
    arr.filter(({checked}) => checked).map(obj => {
        let val = Object.values(obj).find(val => Array.isArray(val));
        return [obj.name].concat(val ? listNames(val) : []);
    }).flat()

const treeMetaData = [{name  :  'database',checked : true,schemas  : [{name  : "schema1",checked : true,tables : [{name  : "table1",checked : true,columns : [{name  : "column1",checked : false,},{name  : "column2",checked : true,}]},]},{name  : "schema2",checked : true,tables : [{name  : "table2",checked : true,columns : [{name  : "column4",checked : true,},{name  : "column5",checked : false,}]},]},]}];
let res = listNames(treeMetaData);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: Why would you think it is not? This may not be the absolute fastest, but it has the advantage that it is more generic and does not need adaptation if your data gets a more deeply nested level. Also it makes no assumptions about the property names for "database", "schema", ...etc.

Comment: Yeah this code is more generic I will test and compare with the other one's Thanks anyways

Comment: How did the tests go?

Answer (score 1):

Seems pretty simple, did you try writing some loops?

```
var result = [];

treeMetaData.forEach(database => {
    if(!database.checked){ return; }
    result.push(database.name);
    database.schemas.forEach(schema => {
        if(!schema.checked){ return; }
        result.push(schema.name);
        schema.tables.forEach(table => {
            if(!table.checked){ return; }
            result.push(table.name);
            table.columns.forEach(column => {
                if(!column.checked){ return; };
                result.push(column.name);               
            });         
        });     
    });
});

//result is now: ["database", "schema1", "table1", "column2", "schema2", "table2", "column4"]
```

Comment: Thanks Mathew quick answer is appreciated !!! Any other good way I have 100000 key values pairs for this operation.

Comment: You could move the sub forEach into the if statement but I'm not sure if an unchecked parent can have a checked child (see ahmeds answer). Regardless I see no other way.

Comment: No unchecked parent have no checked Child

Comment: Updated, should be faster.

Answer (score 0):

Nesting is the answer

```js
const treeMetaData = [
{
  name  :  'database',
  checked : true,
  schemas  : [
    {
      name  : "schema1",
      checked : true,
      tables : [
        {
          name  : "table1",
          checked : true,
          columns : [
            {
              name  : "column1",
              checked : false,
            }, 
            {
              name  : "column2",
              checked : true,
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },
    {
      name  : "schema2",
      checked : true,
      tables : [
        {
          name  : "table2",
          checked : true,
          columns : [
            {
              name  : "column4",
              checked : true,
            }, 
            {
              name  : "column5",
              checked : false,
            }
          ]
        },
      ]
    },

  ]
}]

const result = []

treeMetaData.forEach(item => {
  if(item['checked']){
    result.push(item['name'])
    let schemas = item['schemas']
    schemas.forEach(schema => {
       if(item['checked']){
        result.push(schema['name'])
        let tables = schema['tables']
        tables.forEach(table => {
          if(table['checked']){
            result.push(table['name'])
            let columns = table['columns']
            columns.forEach(column => {
              if(column['checked']){
                result.push(column['name'])
              }
            });
          
          }
        });
       }
    });
    
  }
});

console.log(result)
```